# Change default interface docker container

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, nat

I'm struggling with this problem for two days.

Assumptions:

- Docker network (and interface) named **docknet** type **bridge** subnet **172.18.0.0/16**
- Two interfaces **eth0** (Gateway IP: 192.168.1.1, Interface Static IP: 192.168.1.100) and **eth1** (Gateway IP:192.168.2.1, Interface Static IP: 192.168.2.100)
- Default routing goes through **eth0**

What I want:

- Outgoing traffic from container attached to **docknet** must go to **eth1**

What I tried:

- Default iptable rule created by docker left untouched:

`-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o docknet -j MASQUERADE`

- My rules:

`iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 -j MARK --set-mark 1`

`ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table 2`

Where table 2 is:

`default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1 proto static`

With this setup when I try to ping 8.8.8.8 from a container (172.18.0.2) attached to docknet the following happens:

- 172.18.0.2 gets translated to 192.168.2.1
- the packet goes through eth1
- the packet returns to eth1 with src addr 8.8.8.8 and dst 192.168.2.1

from here a reverse translation from 192.168.2.1 to 172.168.0.2 should happen but running `tcpdump -i any host 8.8.8.8` there is not trace about this translation

I checked out also conntrack -L and this is the result:

> icmp     1 29 src=172.18.0.2 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=9 src=8.8.8.8 dst=192.168.2.1 type=0 code=0 id=9 mark=0 use=1

Useful info:

- eth1 is actually a 4G usb dongle
- ip forwarding is active
- `curl --interface eth1 ipinfo.io` works as expected

EDIT:

output from `ip -d link show eth1`

> eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>       link/ether 00:b0:d6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535

Comment: Do I understand well that in table 2 `via 192.168.2.1` really means "do ARP requests for any internet IP, 4G card will handle it" ? or is the interface not ethernet but a layer 3 interface and/or with NOARP attribute? Or did you intend to put an actual gateway which is not 192.168.2.1? I understand it's not the cause of the issue, but if you could [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/963647/edit) and clarify this point (perhaps even adding some parts of `ip -d link show eth1`, this would avoid confusion.

Comment: @A.B Good catch!

Comment: I added the output of that cmd, A.B the interface is a netgear aircard